# Selenium-webdriver, I cannot go to the modal window

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I am new to automated testing. Faced such a problem, earlier in the test I go to the Iframe window to enter the "test card" data. Instead of "success page", a modal window is displayed on which I need to click. Selenium swears.

..............

```
await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="solid-payment-form-iframe"]'))).then.....
```

..............................

```
`await button46.click().then(async function() {
  bot.sendMessage(-100********, land+"\nTest completed!!✅");
  console.log(button46.click,'SubmitButton - done');
  
  return true//it existed
})  
await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 const number = await driver.wait(
  until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//*[@id="specialOffer"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a'))
  // (By.xpath('//*[@id="specialOffer"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a'))
  , 20000).then(number => {
return driver.wait(
  until.elementIsEnabled(number), 20000)})await number.click();`
```

This is what the console writes:
`ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element <a href="************************************* is not clickable at point (960, 536). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="solid-payment-************************`

Selenium webdriver
javascript
remote server - selenoid(aerokube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX PROBLEM:

````
   await driver.sleep(5000)
  const number1 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//*[@id="specialOffer"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')))
  await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", number1)```
````

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer so everyone can understand it

Answer (score 0):

To click an element with selenium `element.click` the element should be visible and clickable, but your element might be outside of the visible area or might be behind a dialog box. Try clicking by injecting javascript. I have worked with the Python version of selenium so see python code and convert according to your need:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button46)
```

Comment: i need to click element 'number'
if i deleted await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

i have next err:
 TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(xpath, //*[@id="specialOffer"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a)
Wait timed out after 20070ms

Comment: You said deleting `await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` is cauing error then don't delete it, just get the element by this way and after that inject javascript to click button. You might need to see docs for your current selenium version.

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", number)` instead of `number.click()`

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com.ua/en/3xUR42MX

Comment: Read 2nd comment again, you should not comment the line 880 as you said deleting this line is causing error.